# Error occurred when creating object

Tags: magento2, object-manager, object, parameter, construct

I have a plugin with constructor

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Contact\Plugin\Controller\Index;

use \Zend_Validate;
use Magento\Contact\Controller\Index\Post;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http;
use Vendor\Contact\Model\QuestionFactory;

/**
 * Class BeforeQuestionSave
 * @package Vendor\Contact\Plugin\Controller\Index
 */
class BeforeQuestionSave
{
    /**
     * @var Http
     */
    private $getRequest;

    /**
     * @var QuestionFactory
     */
    private $questionFactory;

    /**
     * @var Zend_Validate
     */
    private $zendValidate;

    private $validationNotEmpty;
    /**
     * BeforeQuestionSave constructor.
     * @param Http $request
     * @param QuestionFactory $questionFactory
     * @param Zend_Validate $zenValidate
     */
    public function __construct(
        Http $request,
        QuestionFactory $questionFactory,
        Zend_Validate $zenValidate,
        Zend_Validate_NotEmpty $notEmpty
    ) {
        $this->questionFactory = $questionFactory;
        $this->getRequest = $request;
        $this->zendValidate = $zenValidate;
        $this->validationNotEmpty = $notEmpty;
    }

    /**
     * Before execute
     *
     * @param Post $subject
     */
    public function beforeExecute(Post $subject)
    {
        $data = $this->getRequest->getPostValue();
        if ($this->validatePostData($data)) {
            $question = $this->questionFactory->create();
            $question->setData($data)
                ->setPhone($data['telephone'])
                ->setContent($data['comment'])
                ->save();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Validation method
     *
     * @param array $data
     * @param Zend_Validate $object
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function validatePostData($data)
    {
        $validation = $this->zendValidate;
        $validate = false;
        $validation->addValidator($this->validationNotEmpty);

        if ($validation->isValid(trim($data['name'])) && $validation->isValid(trim($data['telephone']))) {
            $validation->addValidator(new \Zend_Validate_EmailAddress());

            if ($validation->isValid(trim($data['email']))) {
                $validate = true;
            }
        }

        return $validate;
    }
}
```

When i run it i get exception   Type Error occurred when creating object:

> Vendor\Contact\Plugin\Controller\Index\BeforeQuestionSave

I can see below error in my error log:

```
 [2019-08-26 13:37:57] main.CRITICAL: Type Error occurred when creating object: Vendor\Contact\Plugin\Controller\Index\BeforeQuestionSave, Too few arguments to function Vendor\Contact\Plugin\Controller\Index\BeforeQuestionSave::__construct(), 3 passed in /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 116 and exactly 4 expected [] []
[2019-08-26 13:37:57] main.ERROR: Type Error occurred when creating object: Vendor\Contact\Plugin\Controller\Index\BeforeQuestionSave [] []
```

How i can pass 4-th argument?
I try replace new \Zend_Validation_NotEmpty && Email to DI in constuctor

Comment: I get error only when i try to add \Zend_Validate_NotEmpty

Comment: Are you using this "use Magento\Framework\Validator\NotEmpty;" before class Initialization?

Comment: I use \Zend_Validate_NotEmpty

Comment: Can you add your full php file code here?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
public function __construct(
Http $request,
QuestionFactory $questionFactory,
Zend_Validate $zenValidate,
Zend_Validate_NotEmpty $zendValidateNotEmpty
   ) {
   $this->questionFactory = $questionFactory;
  $this->getRequest = $request;
  $this->zendValidate = $zenValidate;
  $this->$zendValidateNotEmpty = $zendValidateNotEmpty;
 }
```

Comment: `Exception #0 (Zend_Validate_Exception): Unknown type

Exception #0 (Zend_Validate_Exception): Unknown type
<pre>#1 Zend_Validate_NotEmpty->__construct(array('type' => NULL)) called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:116]
#2 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Zend_Validate_No...', array(NULL)) called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:66]`